# Chat App, allocation issue. Error on custom class initialization in Xcode (EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, initialization, release

My app is running correctly until I attempt to create an instance of my custom class Transcript. Is my problem coming from the initialization method or the way I am allocating my pointer ? I am perplex since the app doesn't crash. The signal (lldb) appears in the debug area, while the declaration line of my initializer gets underlined in green with the following message:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7ffffc)
```

Here is the complete implementation of my class :

```
- (id)initTranscriptWithID:(NSString *)peerID message:(NSString *)message  direction:(NSString *)direction {
if (self = [super init]) {
    _peerID = peerID;
    _message = message;
    _direction = direction;
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithPeerID:(NSString *)peerID message:(NSString *)message direction:(NSString*)direction
{
return [self initWithPeerID:peerID message:message direction:direction];
}
```

This initializer is called in a view controller the following way, messageSent being a property of the same view controller:

```
Transcript* transcript = [[Transcript alloc]initWithPeerID:    [self.messageReceived objectForKey:@"senderId"] message:[self.messageSent objectForKey:@"content"] direction:@"right"];
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm creating the instance of Transcript correctly in the view controller, however, is there a problem with the declaration of my initializer ?
I have tried to use NSZombieEnabled unsuccessfully. Otherwise, I don't think that I am ever deallocating the instance transcript...

What is the error ? What does my thread exactly correspond to and what is the usual way to tackle these problems ? If you need more information I'd be happy to provide it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Which line is that crashing at?

Comment: Your second method -(id)initWithPeerID:message:direction; is calling itself.....

Answer (score 0):

the method `initWithPeerID` calls itself – I guess in an infinite loop.
You probably mean

```
- (id)initWithPeerID:(NSString *)peerID message:(NSString *)message direction:(NSString*)direction
{
return [self initTranscriptWithID:peerID message:message direction:direction];
}
```

Comment: "initTranscriptWithPeerID" -> "initTranscriptWithID"

Comment: you're right, Phillip, thanks. Darn copy&paste. I fixed it above

Comment: Small mistake but kind of think I can't spot at all! Thank you very much for your help